# Video.js full-screen in IE and Edge browser

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am using http://videojs.com/ . I am seeing full screen mode fail with a black screen on IE and Edge (works in Chrome and Firefox). This also occurs on the demo page at http://videojs.com/. Try making one of the videos full-screen in IE or Edge. On Win 10, here, the video appears to be playing, but there is no picture.

*I am looking for a solution or workaround.*

*Does it fail for you?*

*Under what conditions does this fail/succeed?*

Comment: Works for me on IE 11 and Edge on Windows 10

Comment: Thanks. I suspected this might happen..

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to this - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/edge-browser-crashes-on-full-screen-video/a72e0187-8ade-4a4e-b0c1-3f093f03cfda - a **bug**.

> [Close Edge / IE Browser. Go to Control Panel > Internet Options.
>   Select 'Advanced' tab at the top. Tick 'Use software rendering instead
>   of GPU rendering*', then click OK. Re-open Edge / IE Browser.

*It worked for me.*