# JavaScript requestFullscreen not working in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge, html5-fullscreen

I'm trying to make a video (or anything else) go into a fullscreen mode in the Edge browser through JavaScript. But I can't get it to work. In Chrome everything works as expected.

I tried all steps in the js command line tool. The correct html video element is fetched with the line `document.getElementById("video_player");`. Then I tried to enter the command `video.requestFullscreen();`, but it's not doing anything. Not even an error :(

I have activated the fullscreen API in the about: flags settings and I've turned off all browser extension.

The HTML video element is not inside an `<iframe>`

**EDIT:**

This is my full code. The js file is loaded at the end of the HTML document. As you can see it's not doing much right now.

```
console.log("Running");

var video = document.getElementById("video_player");

FullScreenStart();

function FullScreenStart(){
    console.log("AutoFullScreen started");

    console.log(video);

    if (video.requestFullscreen) {
        video.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        video.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) { 
        video.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}

function FullScreenOn(){
    console.log("FullScreen activated");
}

function FullScreenOff(){
    console.log("FullScreen deactivated");
}

document.onwebkitfullscreenchange = function(evt) {

    if(document.webkitIsFullScreen){
        FullScreenOn();
    } else {
        FullScreenOff();
    }
};
```

Please, can somebody help me to get this to work? I've wasted two days on this problem now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727863/video-js-full-screen-in-ie-and-edge-browser This may be of help.

Comment: @dillon.harless Thanks, but I don't get a black screen. It just does nothing at all :(

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: When I run this code (which should theoretically work with the webkit vendor prefix), I get an "Unspecified Error": https://jsfiddle.net/e9noLhzu/1/ In Chrome, I get a warning that "API can only be initiated by a user gesture.". See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29281986/215552).

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks, I guess I have to find another way to achieve something similar to full screen :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test with your above posted code.

I find that your code will not work in any browser, If you call the fullscreen api using code.

I am not sure, how it works on chrome as you said in original post.

If you refer the documentation than you can find information below.

> Note: This method must be called while responding to a user interaction or a device orientation change; otherwise it will fail.

Reference:

[Element.requestFullscreen()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen)

As said in the documentation, Method get failed in both Chrome and Edge if I call it from code but it works if user try to call it using button click.

Example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fullscreen with JavaScript</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the video in fullscreen mode.</p>
<button onclick="openFullscreen();">Open Video in Fullscreen Mode</button>
<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Press the "Esc" key to exit full screen.</p>

<video width="100%" controls id="myvideo">
  <source src="rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="rain.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script>
/* Get the element you want displayed in fullscreen */ 
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");

/* Function to open fullscreen mode */
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
</script>

<p>Note: Internet Explorer 10 and earlier does not support fullscreen mode.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference:

[HTML DOM requestFullscreen() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_requestfullscreen.asp)

It was done intentionally, Because if it get work from code than so many sites starts showing pop ups without asking permission from user. Which can be annoying for user.

Comment: I have this working on safari (iOS).  I wire up an eventlistener to the video element for 'play' - the video goes to full screen on the iPad but not on Edge